# netty websocket protocols support

Tags: websocket, netty

I tried to look this over in the Netty documentation but was unable to find it : which all websocket protocols does Netty websocket implementation support ?

I am trying to check for browser compatibility and hence also wanted to see the protocols as mentioned above. Going through the websocket server example in Netty 3.5.3 , I see in the `WebSocketServerIndexPage` class that `window.MozWebSocket` is also used , hence am I right that hybi-07 and hybi-10 is also supported without any specific code to be written? (Pardon me I am not much aware of the differences in the various protocols but it seems to be mentioned everywhere).

Comment: Not sure what you're true question is but if you're trying to check for compatibility, js: `typeof window.WebSocket === "function"` condition should do the trick

Comment: @MattLo : I am just trying to look for various protocols Netty implementation supports , since various browsers and versions support different websocket protocols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netty supports protocol versions HyBi 00 (which is the same as Hixie 76), HyBi 8-10 and HyBi 13-17 (17 is the same as IETF 6455).

Each browser supports a single version of the protocol. HyBi 00-76 covers current released versions of iOS. IETF 6455 covers recent versions of Chrome and Firefox (and Opera if once they enable it by default), and IE 10. For browsers without native WebSocket support but with Flash you can use [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) as a fallback and that supports IETF 6455 (albeit without binary data types).

In other words, Netty supports basically all browsers that have WebSocket support.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I've removed the Safari scaremongering from my answer now

Answer (score 1):

According to the netty [api docs](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/package-summary.html), it supports 3 versions of the Hybi drafts - [00](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00), [07](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-07) and [10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-10) as well as [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

This will give you support for most browsers as summarised by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Thanks - I've updated the links now

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.